# Export database from MongoDB Compass and export onto live site

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Compass on my localhost to test my site and get my database setup correctly with my Django models. I have never ran a MongoDB database before but in Compass I do not see the ability to export the database, only collections. Is it possible to dump the entire database and import it into my live site? Or do I have to do each individual collection?

Also, I don't have MongoDB on my live site yet, but I assume it should be just as easy as exporting?

Just want to make sure before I start adding info, or should I just do it all on the live site? It is just nice to have a local version for testing.

Comment: Yes, its possible to export databases. Its very useful for backups as well. https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to dump the entire database and import it into my live site?"

Yes.

To "dump entire database":

```
mongodump --db database_name --collection collection_name
```

To "import into my live site":

```
mongorestore --db database_name <path2bsonfile>
```

mongoexport produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance.

mongodump is a utility for creating a binary export of the contents of a MongoDB instance.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/